How to check which project is unloaded in Visual Studio
I have 350 projects in my solution. The projects are grouped under Solution level folders. While experimenting on few things I unloaded few of the projects (right click on project and Unload Project). However after the Visual Studio is restarted there is no places I can see which are the projects which are unloaded (In Solution Explorer, on top it shows 340 of 350 projects)
Is there any place; in console or Output Window or anywhere else; where it can give the list projects which are currently not loaded?

You can simply type "(unloaded)" in the search box inside the solution explorer view. This answer might be quite obvious, but I really don't see any other built-in options.


Indeed this is so obvious that anybody would miss :D. Thanks for this trick. It definitely serves the purpose.

Usually Visual Studio itself does not have a window that specifically lists unloaded projects, but when you unload a project, there will be an unloaded prompt on the right side of this project:

If there is no such prompt on the right side of your unloaded project, it may be related to one of your custom settings. You can try to reset all settings to see if it works: Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings. If it still doesn't work, please provide a structure diagram of your project if possible, and I will try to reproduce the problem.
In addition, when you try to rebuild the solution, the output window will show the projects that have not been unloaded, which also indirectly reminds you which projects you have unloaded:


This is like browsing the whole solution. This is useful only if there are a handful of projects or more unloaded projects than loaded ones. As I mentioned I have 350 projects of which only 10 are unloaded. Also this will become even more difficult once we have subfolders inside subfolders

I want to know whether there is an unloaded prompt on the right side of the unloaded project. If not, have you tried to reset the user settings? I have tested it again. No matter how many layers of folders are nested, as long as you delete a project, there will be an unloaded prompt on the right side. If you don't want to expand them one by one to see which ones are unloaded and which ones are not, you only need to search for the keyword: unloaded.
